# What happens if I close the tab when deploy project using git branch on dashboard?

Tags: git, heroku

What happens if I close the tab when I'm deploying a project using the online
dashboard?

e.g.:

if I close the browser at this moment (see image) of the deploy. What happens to
the application? will finish the process or abort?

> [image: this moment]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The deploy is running on one of Heroku's servers, and your browser is just tailing the log, so closing your browser will have no effect on the process - the deploy will finish.

This is a perfectly safe thing to just test out:

- Commit something you'd like to deploy
- Start deploying
- Close the browser
- See if it deploys anyway

If it does, success. If it doesn't, no harm done, just click deploy again.